# A silly doubt on notation of Hartle's GR book

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, linear-algebra

Quoting from the text

> [...] Evaluating (20.46) in such coordinates is just like evaluating the derivative of a function (20.1):
>     $$\left( \mathbf{\nabla_t v}\right)^\alpha = t^\beta \frac{\partial v^\alpha}{\partial x^\beta} \quad \text{(LIF)}. \tag{20.47}$$
>     For the tensor $\mathbf{\nabla v}$ we therefore have
>     $$\nabla_\beta v^\alpha = \frac{\partial v^\alpha}{\partial x^\beta} \quad \text{(LIF)}. \tag{20.48}$$
>     (The LIFs have been added as a reminder that the formulas hold only in a local inertial frame at the point $x^\alpha$ where the formula is evaluated.)

I have a silly doubt here: on equation 20.47 we have the compact notation for a covariant derivative on Local inertial Frame. 
Despite the context of GR, I would like to know why in equation 20.48
Hartle say "For the tensor...."(I mean, why and were is the Tensor?) and why in the phrase above, Hartle wrote 
\begin{equation}
\nabla \textbf{v} 
\end{equation}

insted of

\begin{equation}
\nabla _\textbf{t} \textbf{v} 
\end{equation}

and who can I reach on expression 20.48 (from notions constructed on 20.46 (definition of the covariant derivative) and 20.47 +linear algebra and tensor algebra notions)? What suppose to mean the beta on nabla?

I have serious doubt on notation.

Comment: A vector is first order tensor, and the covarient derivative of s tensor is another tensor , (which is the whole  point of  covarience, to preserve tensor properties).

Comment: I replaced the image with a typeset block quote of the text immediately around line 20.7 using a combination of markdown (for the blockquote) and MathJax (for LateX mathmode). You should check that and also determine if more should be quoted

Comment: There is also this site, https://www.onlineocr.net/  which is 90% plus accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a vector $\mathbf{t}$, $\nabla_{\mathbf{t}}\mathbf{v}$ is the covariant derivative of $\mathbf{v}$ in the direction of $\mathbf{t}$, which is another vector (which is why there is only one upper index). $\nabla \mathbf{v}$, however, is not a vector. It's a tensor, because if you give it a vector $\mathbf{t}$ it returns the vector $\nabla_\mathbf{t} \mathbf{v}$. A function which depends linearly on a vector and returns another vector is a $\binom 1 1$ tensor.

If you prefer an argument with indices, you can think of it like this. In an inertial frame the components of  $(\nabla_{\mathbf{t}}\mathbf{v})^\alpha$ are

$$t^\beta \partial_\beta v^\alpha.$$

So the obvious definition of $\nabla \mathbf{v}$ is

$$(\nabla \mathbf{v})_\beta^\alpha = \partial_\beta v^\alpha$$

so that

$$ (\nabla_\mathbf{t} \mathbf{v})^\alpha = t^\beta (\nabla \mathbf{v})_\beta^\alpha = t^\beta \partial_\beta v^\alpha.$$